# Regression returns all statistically insignificant variables

Tags: r, regression

I have a sample of 120 cross border M&A deals from emerging market firms and I am trying to analyze post-M&A performance after 3 years. The data satisfy all assumptions and there is no strong evidence of collinearity. However when running the regression all variables result statistically insignificant. What could be the problem?

I included several controls for firm and deal specific characteristics, and the main independent variables are indicated as predictor 1 through 3

```
> mod<-lm(`Post-acquisitionPerformance`~.,data=mydata)
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = `Post-acquisitionPerformance` ~ ., data = mydata)


                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                  -0.2353037  0.1340577  -1.755   0.0822 .
control 1                     0.0354208  0.0560514   0.632   0.5288  
control 2                     0.0213656  0.0246638   0.866   0.3884  
predictor 2                  -0.0296270  0.0666735  -0.444   0.6577  
control 3                     0.0110906  0.0077667   1.428   0.1564  
control 4                     0.0096196  0.0469441   0.205   0.8380  
predictor 2                  -0.0142046  0.0121282  -1.171   0.2442  
predictor 3                   0.0017482  0.0111459   0.157   0.8757  
predictor1*predictor2        -0.0277102  0.0377849  -0.733   0.4650  
predictor1*predictor3         0.0036785  0.0183584   0.200   0.8416  

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1146 on 102 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1853,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.03355
```

I expected significance for all predictors based on the literature

Comment: The statistical significance depends on how strong your patterns are and the number of observations. If literature gives you reasons to believe that some, or all, of your variables should be found statistically significant, then this most likely means that your sample is not big enough to capture that pattern. Remember, that so far you can say that based on your 120 observations you don't have any evidence that your variables are statistically significant. It doesn't mean that they are not (i.e. you probably need more observations to get that evidence).

Comment: Ok many thanks Antonios for the answer, unfortunately the limited sample size is due to lack of accounting data so it's not something I can easily solve.

Comment: Hi: keep in mind that any t-statistic that comes out of regression output is always conditional on the other regressors being in the model already. so, if you want to test for overall  ( or lack thereof ) statistical significance, you really should be using an F-test.